# How can one get the subprocesses of an NSTask's process?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, process, nstask

If I use an `NSTask` object which is launched, is it possible to get the process invoked by the task? For example, Terminal does this to show it in the title bar:

[image: Terminal screenshot]

How can I get the process invoked by the `NSTask`'s process?

Answer (score 2):

You may access to `[task launchPath]` and then analyze the string you get.